# Bathroom vanity instalation

Tags: plumbing, drain

I am installing a new vanity and the sink will be relocated about 12” off set from the exit pipe coming out of the wall. Is this a problem? And should the P-trap be located closer to the sink or nearer the exit pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the drain is still in the cabinet for aesthetic purposes, and the pipe can still allow the water to flow downhill to the drain in the wall, you can do what you need.

The p-trap is always under the tailpipe of the sink.

Comment: Thanks, so for that 12” horizontal pipe to the wall should be down sloped a little?

Comment: Yes, the pipe is not supposed to hold water, just the p-trap. Slope by code should be 1/4" to the foot.